# Map plt.imread to Fixed Sized array

Tags: python, image, numpy, matplotlib

I am making a certain project that will require me to convert images into a fixed sized array of the per-pixel RGB values of an image. Reading the image is done as follows:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
image = plt.imread("dummy_image.jpg") #Example image with a shape of 32x32
print(image.shape)
```

Which should output:

```py
(32, 32, 3)
```

The problem is that I am looping over hundreds of images, and for each image, I allocated a fixed-size-array (for example 64x64x3) and assigned the per-pixel values individually through a loop.

```py
import numpy as np
arr1 = np.zeros((64, 64, 3))

#Then I looped for each pixel value and assigned it to arr1
x, y, w = image.shape
for i in range(x):
    for j in range(y):
        arr1[i][j] = image[i][j]
```

As you can infer, this piece of code takes too long to finish. What's more, since the size of each image is varying, I can't consolidate it and make a function for `numpy.pad` to fix the image size with zeros.

Can anyone give me tips or tricks for doing this in a more memory efficient and/or time efficient way?

Comment: Do you have to use python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I am understanding is that you have many images that you want to store in RAM. The first question you need to ask yourself is if you actually need to store them all at the same time? For example, can you read one, do some processing, and then only keep the result of the processing before reading the next image?

When it comes to the actual storage, I do not understand why you need the `var1` variable. Isn't image sufficient? If the point of var1 is to have all your images with the same shape, then why cannot you use pad? For example, `imageNew = numpy.pad(image, [(0, x - y) for x, y in zip(arr1.shape, image.shape)])`.

If you cannot use numpy.pad, then would simply `arr1[:image.shape[0], :image.shape[1], :] = image` work for you?

If you want to do it with loops, then use numba.

```
from numba import jit
import numpy as np


@jit(nopython=True)
def resize(image):
    arr1 = np.zeros((64, 64, 3))
    for i in range(image.shape[0]):
        for j in range(image.shape[1]):
            arr1[i][j] = image[i][j]
    return arr1
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! the `numpy.pad` code that you gave worked perfectly!

Comment: No worries, happy processing. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Create initialize the output image

```py
>>> output = np.zeros((3,5,5))
>>> output
array([[[0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]],

       [[0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]],

       [[0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]]])
```

Suppose the input image is of dimensions 2x2

```py
>>> img = np.random.randint(0,256,size=(3,2,2))
>>> img
array([[[ 33, 245],
        [ 77,   8]],

       [[173,  64],
        [ 37, 182]],

       [[130, 225],
        [  1, 117]]])
```

Copy the image to the output image like this:

```py
>>> d,r,c = img.shape
>>> output = np.zeros((3,5,5))
>>> output[:, 0:r, 0:c] = img
>>> output
array([[[ 33., 245.,   0.,   0.,   0.],
        [ 77.,   8.,   0.,   0.,   0.],
        [  0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.],
        [  0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.],
        [  0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.]],

       [[173.,  64.,   0.,   0.,   0.],
        [ 37., 182.,   0.,   0.,   0.],
        [  0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.],
        [  0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.],
        [  0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.]],

       [[130., 225.,   0.,   0.,   0.],
        [  1., 117.,   0.,   0.,   0.],
        [  0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.],
        [  0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.],
        [  0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.]]])
```